# How to use a string entered in a txt file as an if condition

Tags: c++, file-io

A function containing the function of a vector is included in a class called Vector. I will determine which function to use in the main function by the string entered in the txt file.

```cpp
class Vector
{
public: // private?
    double x, y, z;

public:
    Vector() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
    Vector(int _x, int _y, int _z) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
    Vector Add(Vector v) {
        Vector output;
        output.x = x + v.x;
        output.y = y + v.y;
        output.z = z + v.z;
        return output;
    }
    double Dot(Vector v) {
        double output;
        output = (x * v.x) + (y * v.y) + (x * v.y);
        return output;
    }
};
```

This is the main function. I want to use the string that I want to receive in the txt file, but it doesn't work well. A detailed example is below this code.

```cpp
int main()
{
    FILE* fpInput;
    FILE* fpOutput;
    int vectorAx, vectorAy, vectorAz, vectorAdim;
    int vectorBx, vectorBy, vectorBz, vectorBdim;
    char VecFun[10];

    fpInput = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fpInput, "%d %d %d", &vectorAx, &vectorAy, &vectorAz);
    fscanf(fpInput, "%d %d %d", &vectorBx, &vectorBy, &vectorBz);

    fclose(fpInput);

    fpInput = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fgets(VecFun, sizeof(VecFun), fpInput);
    fclose(fpInput);

    Vector vectorA(vectorAx, vectorAy, vectorAz);
    Vector vectorB(vectorBx, vectorBy, vectorBz);

    if (VecFun == "Add") {
        Vector vectorO = vectorA.Add(vectorB);
        fpOutput = fopen("output.txt", "w");
        fprintf(fpOutput, "%.f %.f %.f", vectorO.x, vectorO.y, vectorO.z);
        fclose(fpOutput);
    }
    else if (VecFun == "Dot") {
        fpOutput = fopen("output.txt", "w");
        fprintf(fpOutput, "%.f", vectorA.DotProduct(vectorB));
        fclose(fpOutput);
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid input.. (%s)\n", VecFun);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**input.txt**:

```
Add
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

**ouput.txt**:

```
5 7 9
```

**input.txt**:

```
Dot
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

**ouput.txt**:

```
32
```

However, the if condition did not work, so I tried debugging with:

```cpp
printf("Invalid input.. (%s)\n", VecFun);
```

and found this result:

[image]

Why are these results coming out? Also, how can I modify the if condition to work?

Comment: Don't add the C tag tonC++ code unless you really like downvotes.

Comment: I`m sorry. I didn't think about it properly.

Comment: Please, have a look at [fgets()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets): _Parsing stops if a newline character is found, in which case **str will contain that newline character**_. Have a look where your `)` appears. This is an indicator that your `VecFun` contains `"Add\n"` but not `"Add"` as you might expect (and that's not the same). (Btw. it was clever to delimit the output of your (wrong) input by braces. This is a trick I use always when reporting strings with arbitrary characters. Issues like your can hit one unexpectedly and the delimiters uncover this.) ;-)

Comment: why are you not using an `ifstream` to read from the file? Using C io in C++ is making this code unecessarily complicated

Comment: The reason is because of the stability error, so I was forced to write it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't compare C-style strings for equality using the `==` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004237/10871073). In code like `if (VecFun == "Add")`, both the `VecFun` variable (the name of a `char` array) and the `"Add"` (a string literal) decay to pointers to their first elements; and, since they are *different* items in *different* memory locations, that test will always result in a `false` value.

In **C**, you would need to use the `strcmp` function, as shown in the answer(s) to the question linked above. However, in **C++** (since C++14), you can specify your literals as `std::string` objects, using the [`s` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s); then, tests like `VecFun == "Add"s` will work as expected.<sup>1</sup>

Here's a short demo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;

int main()
{
    char test[10] = "Add";
    // Wrong - comparing two different pointers ...
    if (test == "Add") {
        std::cout << "Raw comparison succeeded!\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Raw comparison failed!\n";
    }
    // Plain "C" way, using the strcmp function ...
    if (strcmp(test, "Add") == 0) {
        std::cout << "strcmp comparison succeeded!\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "strcmp comparison failed!\n";
    }
    // C++ way, using std::string literals ...
    if (test == "Add"s) {
        std::cout << "std::string comparison succeeded!\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "std::string comparison failed!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If your compiler doesn't support the C++14 Standard or string literal operators, you could construct a `std::string` object *explicily* from the literal(s), using expressions like `std::string("Add")` in place of the `"Add"s`.

Comment: Note also that, as mentioned in the comments on your question, you will need to address the fact that the `fgets` function will leave the trailing newline character in the string it returns.

Comment: ```if (!strcmp(VecFun, "Add"))``` I changed the code in this way, but there is another problem. I don't know how to prevent a string from containing a newline character.

Comment: @Keastmin Then add a newline to the end of the test literal: `"Add\n"`

Comment: I tried ```if (!strcmp(VecFun, "Add\n"))```, ```if (strcmp(VecFun, "Add\n") == 0)```,

```if (strcmp(VecFun, "Add\n"))``` ,  ```if (!strcmp(VecFun, "Add"))```.  But all skip 'if' and 'else' works. In the txt file, I wrote Add well.

Comment: @Keastmin Have you tried setting the fourth character of your input to the nul terminator **before** the tests: `VecFun[3] = 0;`? (But then don't include the `\n` in the literal!)

Comment: ```char VecFun[10];```, ```char VecFun[10] = {};```, ```char VecFun[10] = "";``` I tested these three things. But the results were the same.

Comment: Add the `VecFun[3] = 0;` line after you have read the line from the input.txt. You also have issues in your code when scanning the 6 numbers, because the "Add" line will be in the way. Read that line first, then do the two scanf reads. All in the same opening session: no need to close then reopen the file.